# Need best case scenario

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, data-structures

My input is `const` **:**

```
input = [
  ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 ];
```

// Expected output

```
const output = ["A", "a", 1, "B", "b", 2, "C", "c", 3, "D", 4, 5, 6];
```

So I write a JavaScript code to achieve output,

```
Array.prototype.insert = function ( index, item ) {
    this.splice( index, 0, item );
};
let lengthInputArray = input.length;
let outputArray = [];
let lengthArray = [];
for(let indexInput = 0; indexInput < input.length; indexInput++){
  lengthArray.push(input[indexInput].length);
}
let maxLen = Math.max(...lengthArray);

for(let maxIndex = 0; maxIndex < maxLen; maxIndex++){
  for (var indexArr of input) {
    if(indexArr.length <= maxLen){
      var tobeInsertValue = indexArr[maxIndex];
      if(tobeInsertValue != undefined){
        outputArray.push(tobeInsertValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log("outputArray : " + outputArray);
```

Can anybody suggest me about good solution or optimum way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try transposing the array based on the longest array index then use `flat` and `filter` to bring out the flatten form without any undefined elements (undefined due to the unequal length of array elements)

```js
let input = [
  ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];
  
let arrayLen = input.map(x => x.length);
let maxLen = Math.max(...arrayLen)
let maxIndex = arrayLen.indexOf(maxLen)
console.log(input[maxIndex].map((_, colIndex) => input.map(row => row[colIndex])).flat().filter(x => x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple nested loop can work, as long as you appropriately handle the ending length:

```js
const input = [
  ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];

const maxLen = Math.max(...input.map(({ length }) => length));

let out = [];

for (let i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
    if (input[j].length > i) {
      out.push(input[j][i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(out);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

I looped through each of the sub-arrays in order, and add the values at the correct position to the output array in their correct order.